# What is the physical meaning of $v\times n$?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

What is the physical meaning of $v\times n$, where $v$ is a velocity vector and and $n$ is a unit normal vector of a interface? Why at the free surface between two fluids,
$$v^{(1)}\times n=v^{(2)}\times n,$$
where $v^{(1)}$ and $v^{(2)}$ are velocity vectors on both sides of the surface.

Problem solved.

Comment: When you ask about physical interpretations, consider physics stack exchange in the future...

Comment: Well, as the content suggested, this should be in PhysicsSE instead. If you want to ask science question, it's ok, but the math part only in MSE.

Comment: "at the free surface"...? What does that mean

Comment: Use the fact that $||v \times n||=||v||||n||sin \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $v$ and $n$ and $||v||sin \theta$ is the length of the altitude from $v$ to $n$. Since a free surface is not being acted on by any force, isn't that the same as saying the net force on both sides cancel each other out, and are thus equal?

Comment: @Nameless ''at the interface'  is  a more appropriate term.

Comment: @Asker I think there is another equation for that, called the momentum conservation.

Comment: Is this not simply that the velocities of the fluids parallel to the interface surface have to match?

Comment: @Chappers Yes, that is the tangential velocity. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This condition means that the tangential components of the velocities of the two fluids are the same at their interface. It is equivalent to saying that there is no slip between the two fluids.

Equality of tangential components is not restricted to fluid dynamics alone. You can find them in [electrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_conditions_for_electromagnetic_fields) as well, where the tangential component of the $\vec{E}$ field are required to be continuous across an interface while that of $\vec{H}$ are discontinuous in the presence of surface currents.

Answer (score 0):

It is a common misunderstanding to say that $\hat{n} \times \mathbf{v}$ is the tangential or transverse velocity.  This vector is orthogonal to both $\mathbf{v}$ and $\hat{n}$, so it is not a component of either vector.  The transverse-to-$\hat{n}$ component of $\mathbf{v}$ is defined as:

$$
\mathbf{v}_{t} = \hat{n} \times \left( \mathbf{v} \times \hat{n} \right)
$$

The form you show is derived from an assumption of boundary conditions.  In this particular case, it looks like a conservation of vorticity across a boundary, where $\nabla \times \mathbf{v}$ $\rightarrow$ $\hat{n} \times \mathbf{v}$.

Another form of this type is used for plane electromagnetic waves.  One assumes that $\delta \mathbf{B}$ and $\delta \mathbf{E}$ are orthogonal to the propagation direction $\mathbf{k}$.  Then using Maxwell's equations and some assumptions, one can then show that:

$$
\nabla \cdot \delta \mathbf{B} \rightarrow \hat{n} \cdot \left( \delta \mathbf{B}_{2} - \delta \mathbf{B}_{1} \right) = 0 \\
\nabla \times \delta \mathbf{E} \rightarrow \hat{n} \times \left( \delta \mathbf{E}_{2} - \delta \mathbf{E}_{1} \right) = 0
$$

The first equation derives from the assumption that there are no magnetic monopoles (I think there are more subtleties involved too, but this is easy enough for now) and the second from the first, since $\nabla \times \delta \mathbf{E}$ = $- \partial_{t} \mathbf{B}$ and that one can show $\oint \mathbf{E} \cdot d\mathbf{l} = 0$ here.